# Sublime text 3 - Shortcut with with folder opened

Tags: sublimetext3

I am Windows user (Win10) and I installed ST3. Since I have several projects/folders to open with ST3, I would like to automate it little bit.

I am thinking to crate an ST3 shortcuts on my desctop and name them with the corresponding project name/alias.

The shortcut is created successfully

`Target: "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"`

And for start in I add the corresponding folder:

`Start in: \\192.168.0.110\share\sshub-api`

It opens the Application but not with the desired folder in the project explorer.

Any ideas are very much welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "start in" doesn't control where sublimes "project" is opened. Instead Sublime can be called with the first argument being the folder you wish to open.

You can pass your project by changing your `Target` to be:

`"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "\\192.168.0.110\share\sshub-api"`

Not sure how it will deal with the network location but I did verify it works with a folder on my `C` drive

Comment: It works with network locations just as well as regular ones. At least in my case.